# Spark distinct by multiple column and condition is or

Tags: apache-spark

datafram1 like this:

```
id    no    name
1     101    aaa
2     102    bbb
3     103    ccc
```

datafram2 like this:

```
id    no    name
4     101    aaa
2     106    bbb
7     107    ccc
```

I want to distinct by id or no, so I want to result dataframe like this
result dataframe:

```
id    no    name
3     103    ccc
7     107    ccc
```

How to get this result by scala spark

Comment: SO is not a free coding service, please show us some attempt to do it first

Comment: Did you tried using dropDuplicates() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Window` function. Check below code.

`duplicateCount` function which takes multiple columns & apply `count(*) over(..)` window function to each column.

```
scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions._
scala> def duplicateCount(columns:String*) = columns
.map(c => count(col("*")).over(Window.partitionBy(col(c)).orderBy(col(c))))
.reduce(_ * _)
```

```
scala> dfa.show(false)
+---+---+----+
|id |no |name|
+---+---+----+
|1  |101|aaa |
|2  |102|bbb |
|3  |103|ccc |
+---+---+----+
```

```
scala> dfb.show(false)
+---+---+----+
|id |no |name|
+---+---+----+
|4  |101|aaa |
|2  |106|bbb |
|7  |107|ccc |
+---+---+----+
```

Filtering duplicate records

```
scala> val finalDf = dfa
.union(dfb)
.withColumn("count",duplicateCount("id","no"))
.filter($"count" === 1)
.drop("count")
```

Final Output

```
finalDF.show(false)
+---+---+----+
|id |no |name|
+---+---+----+
|3  |103|ccc |
|7  |107|ccc |
+---+---+----+
```